# Should we explicitely mark political discussions as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I'm asking because a Stack Overflow employee had reached me because of one of the arguable episodes that had happened this summer and asked to clarify this issue.

My position on this is following: We definitely should do that. Here's why:

1. Actually de-facto this is a site about Russian language. Just like we don't discuss here about our favorite movies and music or our tastes in programming languages or religion, just the same way politics is off-topic here.
2. Because discussing politics is a very subtle issue, especially among Russian-speaking communities, it is still worth to once again explicitely mention the fact that it is off-topic here.
3. Let's be honest, it's very flame-prone.

Keep in mind that I'm strong believer this should be a thing not because I have or have not any strong political affiliations of any kind but because it easily can ruin the atmosphere and user experience for this particular Stack.

Any thoughts, comments, objections?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Honestly I didn't even think that could be a discussion matter.

Politics, religion, food preferences, sexuality and other sensitive subjects should be considered strictly off-topic.

There might be borderline situations, but I would rather delete questions about sensitive topics on sight than waste everyone's time trying to settle a flame war.

Comment: Here's the quote from letter "You mentioned that it is not appropriate to discuss politics on the site, but I could not find any policy about that on your meta site, and that isn't a network-wide policy. " So I guess we should just clarify community rules.